# Statistically Estimating Fixed and Variable Costs Using Least Squares Regression

Tags: regression, least-squares

I have been tasked with exploring the possibility of estimating the fixed and variable price of a hotel room using a statistical approach. I am by no means an expert in this field, so please ignore or correct any ignorance from my part.

Having researched, I came upon the High-Low method of estimating the fixed and variable costs of a hotel room, which then lead me to the Least Squares Method. I have calculated the regression, but am now stuck on interpreting it and working out whether it's any good or whether there are any better options. The formulae I used are:

$$\text{Variable Cost} = b = \frac{n\sum{xy}-\sum{x}.\sum{y}}{n\sum{x}^2-(\sum{x})^2}$$
and
$$\text{Fixed Cost} = a = \frac{\sum{y}-b\sum{x}}{n}$$

where:

$n$ is the number of months

$\sum{y}$ is the sum of total cost

$\sum{x}$ is the sum of rooms sold by month

$\sum{xy}$ is the sum of the products of costs and rooms sold

$\sum{x}^2$ is the sum of squares of rooms sold by month

Here are the expenses and rooms sold detailed by month:

[image: By Month]

Using this data I get to:

$$b = \frac{12\times14306709000-1940000\times85196}{12\times612507754-1940000^2}\approx69.77$$

$$a = \frac{85196-69.77*1940000}{12}\approx-333672.64$$

My question is this. If this is indeed the calculation of fixed and variable cost, how can I have a negative fixed monthly cost? Have I completely misunderstood? How would I effectively come up with a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check your formulas, but $a$ is your intercept, that is the value of your dependent variable (I assume Total Expenses) when your independent variable (I assume Rooms Sold) is equal to 0. This may not be an interesting or even useful number in your case, since from the sample data you provided I can see that no value of the Rooms Sold variable is close to 0. Linear regression is valid only in the interval of your data, so if your (only) independent variable Rooms Sold is in the interval of say 5000 and 7000, then you can interpret the results of Total Expenses only in this interval, outside of this interval is extrapolation.

So for example if we check the predicted value of Total Expenses for 5000 Rooms Sold then
$−333672.64+69.77*5000=15177.36$, which looks reasonable.